# Updating Nuget Package of the Same Version Number

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard

I'm developing a .net Standard C# class library which automatically outputs a NuGet package whenever I build it.  I am consuming this NuGet package with an ASP.NET Core application.  If I update the version number of the class library each time I build it, I can pull in the changes into my application using a simple Update-Package command, but I don't want to have to change the version number each time, when I'm making lots of small changes.

I've tried clearing the NuGet cache in the Visual Studio Options menu and then tried using "dotnet restore" and also Uninstall / ReInstall, but somehow it still seems to keep pulling in an older version from somewhere.

Is there any other way of doing this?  Where would it be pulling the older version from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's simply not how NuGet works. Version numbers are idempotent, so you cannot "replace" a version; you can only increment it. This is a rule of [SemVer](https://semver.org/) (semantic versioning), which NuGet follows. The rule states:

> Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version.
>   (https://semver.org/#spec-item-3)

There's two things that can help you, though.

1. NuGet employs [SemVer](https://semver.org/), so you should as well. In development, you do not increment the major, minor or patch numbers (`[major].[minor].[patch]`). Instead, you add a dash, followed by a prerelease identifier, i.e. `1.0.0-alpha.1`. This then allows you to increment the identifier without affecting your release numbers. For example, your next change might be `1.0.0-alpha.2`, and when you're finally ready for release, you only then use just `1.0.0`.
2. In development, you shouldn't be modifying your NuGet in conjunction with your app code. If they're in the same solution, a package reference is unnecessary, as a project reference makes more sense, and with that, no version increment is necessary. You should only be including via package reference if the library is in a different solution than your app, and then, you should be developing the two independently. You can also separate the projects later, if that makes more sense. If your library isn't developed enough to be able to support your app without constant changes, then keep it in the same solution. Once it reaches a stable point, you can then move it out to its own solution if that's what you prefer, and change the reference in your app at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, very helpful.  It is in a separate solution as there is another developer who is using it for a different application.  We are both making changes to the class library and both making changes to the 2 consuming applications.  I guess we will have to make use of your suggestion of a pre-release identifier.  I don't mind changing it each time I checkin a change for the other developer to use, it just seems silly doing it as I'm coding it.  Would be much easier if it was all in the same solution but then the other developer wouldn't be able to use it / contribute.

Comment: That's more of an issue of team organization. Two developers should never be touching the same code at the same time. Someone needs to take ownership of the library, at least in the context of a particular PBI or user story.

Comment: Additionally, if it's an externalized dependency, then necessary changes need to be separated from PBIs related to the apps under development. In other words, if you're working in your app, and you notice a change needs to be made in the library. Then you create an entirely different PBI for that change. At which point, the team or developer responsible for the library can pick it up and implement the change. That may be the same developer in some cases, but this type of organization keeps the change queue separate and structured.

Comment: you can also temporarily add the shared project to your solution, change the package reference to a project reference, and then undo these temporary changes once development is done and you're ready to publish the nuget package.

Answer (score 6):

You can apply this version to your pre-release package to get a package per build :

```
<Version>1.0.0-$(Configuration)-$(Platform)-$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(yyyyMMdd-HHmmss))</Version>
```

Then when you release your package, you change the version with :

```
<Version>1.0.0</Version>
```

You always have to do the upgrade of package but it's version is not incremented

Answer (score 2):

In the Nuget world there is no intuitive way of doing it.

The way I usually resort to is including the project in the solution and work on it. Once I am happy, I would then build the nuget package.

Answer (score 1):

For people still looking for a way to do this the solution that worked best for me is clearing the NuGet cache.

1. Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings menu.
2. Click Clear All NuGet Cache(s) button
3. Rebuild your solution

[image]

Comment: best and simplest solution by far.